# Javascript - Função Esconder DIV não funciona

Tags: javascript

Olá

Eu tenho uma div em minha pagina que esta definida como ( display: none ) e ao clicar no link esconde ou exibe, mas não estou entendendo porque minha função não esta funcionando.

Código:

```
function esconder(el)
{
  var esconder = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
  if(esconder == "none")
    {
     alert("Exibir: " + el);
     esconder.style.display = "block";
    }
   else
    {
     alert("Esconder: " + el);
     esconder.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tens um problema no teu código, `esconder` não é uma referência ao elemento, mas sim uma string com o estado do `display`.

Ou seja, a linha `var esconder = document.getElementById(el).style.display;` vai fazer com que `esconder` seja uma string com `"none"` ou `"block"` e por isso não podes usar `esconder.style.display = "block";`, pois seria o mesmo que

```
"none".style.display = "block";
```

Usa `var esconder = document.getElementById(el);` e assim já ficas com uma referência ao elemento:

```
function esconder(el) {
    var esconder = document.getElementById(el);
    if (esconder.style.display == "none") {
        alert("Exibir: " + el);
        esconder.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        alert("Esconder: " + el);
        esconder.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Sérgio, mas eu não entendi sua explicação muito bem.

Comment: @abduzeedo o que ele disse é que quando você fez isso `var esconder = document.getElementById(el).style.display;` e tentou rodar isso depois `esconder.style.display = "block";` seria o mesmo que fazer isso: `document.getElementById(el).style.display.style.display = "block";`, isso esta errado.

Comment: @abduzeedo juntei uma explicação mais detalhada.

Comment: Perfeito, agora eu entendi, realmente não fazia sentido meu codigo, obrigado